# yarn pngquant & libpng self signed certificate error

Tags: certificate, gatsby, yarnpkg, self-signed, libpng

I am attempting to install gatsby-transformer-sharp gatsby-plugin-sharp using yarn.

Unfortunately when I try and install them the following error displays:

```
error /Users/david.hewitt/code/shopfront/node_modules/pngquant-bin: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node lib/install.js
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/david.hewitt/code/shopfront/node_modules/pngquant-bin
Output:
⚠ self signed certificate in certificate chain
  ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng is installed
    at /Users/david.hewitt/code/shopfront/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
```

It's worth mentioning that this installs correctly when I am at home however, I work at a fintech where we have security in place for vpn's and such.

Is there a way of determining what certificate it is talking about and is there any way to get past this error?

Also I have tried installing libpng locally using brew and defining the certificate in my yarn config.

Comment: When you're browsing are you using a proxy at work? There is some routers that will actually respond to any HTTP request.

Comment: I am sure there is a proxy in place in our repo we have a .yarnrc file which has the registry set differently to the yarn default

Answer (score 0):

Usually in enterprises with corporate proxies, SSL termination is performed so you never see the third-party certificates but self-signed certificates generated on the fly by the internal infrastructure, which is probably why you get this error.

To work around this, you usually need to have an internal repository for your packages (which is useful in any case for larger organizations, for various reasons). That infrastructure then takes care of downloading/caching dependencies and avoiding issues with said proxy and certificates and to point your tools towards that package repo; there are many vendors in this space...

Alternatively, with yarn (and most similar tools), you can bypass certificate checks, but we all agree that it is a really bad idea.

With yarn, you can do this: `yarn config set "strict-ssl" false`

Comment: I am sure people would start shouting at me if I started using `"strict-ssl" = false`. I am sure my company already has the internal repository you are referring to as the .yarnrc file has an entry for `registry` which points to an internal url

Comment: TBH I would probably should at you too :)

Comment: Sometimes, npm packages make http requests to fetch data upon install, which might explain why you end up with this even though there is an internal npm registry. You could probably verify that using Wireshark with the help of your networking team. We had a similar issue once with a package and we've ended up putting a proxy in place with an internal reverse proxy for these cases. Can't remember the specifics though